# Loop through column data in DGV and INSERT into SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, datagridview

I am currently working in windows form application using vb.net express 2013. I have a datagridview and I am trying to loop through one column and insert all the dates from that column into an sql database. Something is wrong. Here is my code:

```
     For cn As Integer = 0 To Datagridview.RowCount - 1
        Dim variable1 As Date = Datagridview.Rows(cn).Cells(1).Value

        'sql code
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (columns) VALUES (values)", conn1)
                With comm1.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@Value1", variable1)
                    .AddWithValue("@Name", CBName.ValueMember)
                End With
```

comm1.ExecuteReader()
                    End Using
                    conn1.Close()
                End Using
        Next

The variable 1 is the date and i am just pulling the name from a combobox. The values and columns are a bunch of values to set the table up. I dont literally have my code saying "columns" and "values". I am not receiving an error message. It is just not writing into the sql table.

ended up missing my execute command.....I bring shame upon my family

Comment: Can you debug your code and verify that it is in fact getting inside the two `Using` statement and hitting the code in there? If so, can you grab out one of the sql statements that it generates and run it in a sql query window via sql management studio (or whatever tool you use) to see if it is updating your table that way? Since we cannot see your real code, it's possible you have an error in your sql script and it is updating zero records in the table.

Comment: Yea, i can check my sql table with management studio. give me one sec.

Comment: there is no execute anywhere

Comment: Ahhhh, there is a problem with my sql statement, im getting my data types mixed up. Let me get that figured out and see if it works.

Comment: Well actually, after taking a second look i threw in an integer for my smalldatetime data type, it was a human error in the management studio. Can you see anything else that would cause the code to fail. Let me update my code.

Comment: @Plutonix missing my execute command, let me tell you how stupid i feel right now......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final code that worked, was missing my execute command, nothing to see here, move along.

```
        Try

            Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                conn1.Open()
                Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (columns) VALUES (values)", conn1)
                    With comm1.Parameters
                        .AddWithValue("@Shear", variable1)
                        .AddWithValue("@Name", combobox)
                    End With
                    comm1.ExecuteReader()
                End Using
                conn1.Close()
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Next
```

Comment: it happens...usually I find 2 other things along the way that need attention